# Kentico Transformation - Macro within Macro

Tags: transformation, kentico

I wish to output a Button on to the screen if there is anything returned from the database. The following is what I want to achieve:

`<%# IfEmpty(Eval("Link1URL"), "", "<a href="<%#Eval("Link1URL")%>" class="btn"> <%#Eval("Link1Title")%> </a>")) %>`

What I am trying to say here is, If the field `Link1Url` is **empty**, then display nothing. Otherwise, display an `<a>` tag with the `Link1URL` field as the `href`.

This doesn't work as the inner macro: `<a href="<%#Eval("Link1URL")%>` messes things up for the outer `IfEmpty` macro.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used .Net `string.IsNullOrEmpty` in the macro to help me next the logic:

`<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("Link2URL")) ? "<a href='" + Eval("Link2URL") + "'>" + Eval("Link2Title") + "</a>" : null %>`

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced scenarios you could use `asp:Placeholder`

Here's an example:

```
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Foo").ToString()) %>' >
   <div class="foo-structure">
      ...
   </div>
</asp:Placeholder>
```

Conditional layout changes within transformations are discussed [here](http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums.aspx?forumid=65&threadid=40763).

**Spoiler** All of those approaches are hacky.